# generators for derived category

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, algebraic-groups, derived-categories

Let $G$ be a algabraic group $G$ over a field $k$. We denote by $D^b(\mathrm{Repr}(G))$ the derived category of finite dimensional representations. Under what kind of assmumptions one has a generating object for $D^b(\mathrm{Repr}(G))$? I mean for finite groups this is clear, since one can take all irreducible representations. For reductive groups this is not possible. Are there examples of groups where this can happen?

Comment: For any unipotent group,the trivial representation does the job.

Comment: Ok, and why does the trivial representation work? (Is there any restriction to the characteristic?)

Comment: Any representation of a unipotent group contains the trivial representation, hence, by induction, is a successive extension of trivial representations. No restriction on the characteristic.

Comment: There's more than one meaning of "generating" for derived categories. Could you clarify exactly what you mean by "generating object"?

Comment: Generating in the sense that the smallest full triangulated subcategory containing that object is equivalent to the hole category.

Comment: @ abx; does this hold for arbitrary unipotent groups or do you assume $G$ to be affine?

Comment: You can get much further if you take a weaker notion of generating object, namely generating the ordinary representation category as a tensor category with duals. For compact groups any faithful representation does the job and probably this is true for algebraic groups as well although I haven't checked.

Comment: @Aleksa: are there non affine unipotent groups?

Comment: @Aleksa: With that definition of generating, then there's only a generating object if the only irreducible representation is the trivial one, so even finite groups won't have them (except $p$-groups in characteristic $p$, and the trivial group).

Comment: But for finite groups one can take the sum of all irreducible representations. This object generates $D^b(\mathrm{Repr}(G))$.

Comment: @Aleksa: Not in the sense you described. Do you actually mean "generates as a thick subcategory" (i.e., as a triangulated category closed under taking direct summands)? In that case there's a generating object iff there are finitely many irreducible.

Comment: I mean in the sense taking direct sums and summands and cones (as in the definition of tilting sheaf for example). This is exactely thick subcategory. Can you give an argument why it is actually if and only if?

Comment: Furthermore, the only algebraic groups having finitely many irreducible representations are the finite one, right?

Comment: @Aleksa: For "if": the direct sum of irreducibles works, since any representation can be constructed from the irreducibles by iterated extensions. For "only if": only finitely many irreducibles occur as composition factors of the homology of an object $X$, and the thick subcategory generated by $X$ contains no objects that have other irreducibles involved.

Comment: So one has that such a generating object exists if and only if the algebraic group is finite.

Comment: No. Unipotent groups, for example.

Comment: Is there any classification of algebraic groups having finitely many irreducible representations?

Comment: @Jeremy Rickard: does the above argument concerning finitely many representations work over arbitrary characteristic?

Comment: @Aleksa: Yes. All it uses is the existence of composition series and the Jordan-Hölder theorem.

Comment: @Jeremy Rickard: Why do unipotent Groups admit finitely many irreducible representations? (Do you have any references?)

Comment: @user45766 Demazure-Gabriel, *Groupes Algébriques* Chapter IV section 2, Proposition 2.5 implies the only irrep is trivial (as abx mentioned way up near the top).